# Generate datetime format for XML

Tags: xml, c#-3.0

I'm trying to generate timestamp for cXML as shown below. Is there any function in C# which I can use to format date time to: 2011-06-09T16:37:17+16:37

e.g.

```
<cXML payloadID="accountsuser@bla.com"
timestamp="2011-06-09T16:37:17+16:37">
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `+16:37` part? In [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_time) it's used for time zone, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the "o" format specifier - read about this one in the [standard Date and Time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) documentation on MSDN.

> The pattern for this specifier reflects a defined standard (ISO 8601).

And:

> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 2009-06-15T13:45:30.0900000

```
string formatted = DateTime.Now.ToString("o");
```

If this is not what you want, you will need to use a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) - I believe you will need to do this, as the offset is not standard.

```
string formatted = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK");
```

Comment: Please, also see the second answer to this. Using "o", you need to "handle" UTC, many times unnecessary to local applications. "s" will due for me!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, using `DateTime.ToString("s")`, see this link: [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Sortable). Be aware that `"s"` does not include the timezone information, whereas `"o"` does include both fractional seconds and timezone.

You can also use the [`XmlConvert.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162344.aspx) method, where you can specify the time zone information as well.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of a date declaration in a schema:

```
<xs:element name="start" type="xs:date"/>
```

An element in your document might look like this:

```
<start>2002-09-24</start>
```

To specify a time zone, you can either enter a date in UTC time by adding a "Z" behind the date:

```
<start>2002-09-24Z</start>
```

or you can specify an offset from the UTC time by adding a positive or negative time behind the date:

```
<start>2002-09-24-06:00</start>
```

or

```
<start>2002-09-24+06:00</start>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ToString method

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;              
string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";   // or any format you want  
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format));
```