# From c# datetime to xsd:datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, soap, xsd

I'm sure it is somehow explained here before but I can't seem to get the exact format I want.
I need to convert DateTime object in C# to xsd:dateTime object.

The result should look something like this:

```
 2014-11-19T21:59:59+02:0
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314154/generate-datetime-format-for-xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People generally use [The `"O"` or `"o"` standard format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Roundtrip) for this. This format always generates `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK"` format no matter which culture you use.

But this doesn't match what you need. You need to use [custom date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 11, 19, 21, 59, 59, DateTimeKind.Local);
dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK");
```

result will be;

```
2014-11-19T21:59:59+02:00
```

Then you can use [`String.Substring` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to delete your last character like;

```
.Substring(0, dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK").Length - 1)
```

Remember, this [`"K"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#KSpecifier) only generates [UTC Offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) part of your current time zone if your `DateTimeKind` is `Local`. For `Utc`, it generates `Z` character and for `Unspecified` it generates empty string.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it doesn't give me the result you specified. All the results the I could discover are generating the 'fffffffK' part.

Comment: Eventually, I used your idea with the substring. Just need to realign it according to what the actual result. Thanks.

Comment: @Moutabreath You can't get a format like `..+02:0` if you use `O or o` standard format. You should use a custom date and time format and use `Substring` method as I mentioned. I don't think there can be another solution in your case.

Comment: I couldn't even get your format with the extra digit at the end. I needed a bit more complex usage of substring.

Comment: @Moutabreath What is your `DateTime`'s `Kind` property exactly? Which format do you use? What kind of complex usage are you looking for?

Comment: I'm not looking for a complex usage of datetime. I had to use substring in a more complex way in order to get what I need. What I use was your code and it generated at time format with the extra 'ffff'

Comment: @Moutabreath Can you give a few examples about your cases? My `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK` format doesn't generate milliseconds part with `ffff`. Only `O or o` standard date and time format can get.